# Downgrade form php5 5.3.10 to php5 5.3.2 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php

i wanted to install php5 5.3.2, so first deleted all the php5 files

```
 sudo apt-get purge php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql
```

and also delete the deb files form

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

so now there is no deb file on the system then i add this person repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:sushkov/personal
```

because he add php5.3.2 and then i updated it and upgraded it

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then i installed php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql
```

now when i check the php version it says php5.3.10

and when i run this command

```
sudo apt-cache show php5
```

it says

```
Package: php5
Version: 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Guillaume Plessis <gui@dotdeb.org>
Installed-Size: 0
Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0) | php5-cgi (>= 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0) | php5-fpm (>= 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0), php5-common (>= 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0)
Filename: dists/squeeze/php5/binary-i386/php5_5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0_all.deb
```

now i dont know how to downgrade, is there any way that i change something in the repository and write

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

it will install php5.3.2 which i want instead of php5.3.10

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the version 5.3.2 that was available in Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that you remove any php reference.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

To remove package and config files

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove <Package Name>
```

To remove unused dependencies and config files

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Download php5 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 from [Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/security/php5).  Once downloaded, navigate to the folder where the file was saved, probably ***Downloads***, and run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i < package name>
```

Or use GDebi.  To install it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal.  When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Or click below

[image]

Once you have installed GDebi, use the File Browser to find the package you wish to install, and double click on it.

Comment: Sorry i need php5 5.3.2 not 5.3.10 and still when i download this, the package gives error, it opens in ubuntu software center.

Comment: Its available [Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/lucid/main/updates/php5).  Download the All arch deb package

Answer (score 2):

According to [ppa:sushkov/personal](https://launchpad.net/~sushkov/+archive/personal) page , the PPA is available only till **Ubuntu 10.04** and **NOT for Ubuntu 12.04** so even if you add the PPA it will  give you error as

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sushkov/personal/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sushkov/personal/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sushkov/personal/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

And if you  are still eager to get the **5.3.2 version** , download it manually from [PPA package builds page](https://launchpad.net/~sushkov/+archive/personal/+packages) , by expanding the arrow key as

[image]

Well , it is **HIGHLY RECOMMENDED** to use the updated Package version 5.3.10 Available through Official Repository for Security reasons.

**EDIT** : Download all the packages ending with **i386.deb** since your system seems to be 32-bit and run the following command from the downloaded directory

**`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`**

Also he provided a **`all.deb`** file at the end try installing it **first** then follow the above command.

If you want to compile from source package first install **build-essential** if not present through

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then download [php5_5.3.2.orig.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/~sushkov/+archive/personal/+files/php5_5.3.2.orig.tar.gz) then unpack or extract it and run from the extracted directory

**`./configure && make && sudo make install`**

**P.S. :** May not work at all , since two years old release .

Comment: Ok thankx, but is there a way to have one deb file instead of i download all there files and then install it

Comment: Thanks, if this dont work, where can i get php source for ubuntu so that i can compile it and run myself, but i dont know how to compile it can you also provide me link, that wil be helpfull

Comment: @iori -  See answer , edited.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would really discourage you from using severaly outdated version of PHP full of security bugs.

And to answer your sort of hidden question – you have manually added dotdeb repository which provides more recent version of PHP5, so you need to remove it from your apt sources.  Look into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Also I would like to show you the command you might find usefull in such situations:

```
$ apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.4.4-13
  Version table:
     5.4.4-13 0
        500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

It will show you the available versions and install candidates together with the package sources in case there are more versions available.